# Activity class MainActivity doesn't exist . I dont know why?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

When I run my code in my phone, It is not running. I'm worried about it.Can't figure out what the problem is.I have 5 java files(I don't know if I can call it as activity) MainActivity.java, MainActivity2.java, Person.java, DatabaseHandler.java, GetDetails.java. and activity_main.xml, front_page.xml, refer_mail.xml
Its a lengthy post. sorry for that.

This is my console message.

```
[2015-08-28 19:23:58 - FormDetails] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2015-08-28 19:23:58 - FormDetails] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.Prasad.formdetails/com.Prasad.formdetails.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

This is my MainActivity.java File.

```
package com.Prasad.formdetails;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {     

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
    Button details=(Button)findViewById(R.id.get_details);

    //Register Functionality
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    //Get Details Functionality
    details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetDetails.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}


}
```

This is my AndroidManifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.Prasad.formdetails"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity2" />
    <activity android:name=".GetDetails" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Clean de project in Project->Clean and try again.

Comment: you should generally not have capitals in a package name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `android:enabled="false"` from Your Application Tag. Then **Clean,Rebuild And Restart** Your Project .Try this way .I hope it will helps you

### android:enabled

Whether or not the Android system can instantiate components of the application — `"true"` if it can, and "false" if not. If the value is `"true"`, each component's enabled attribute determines whether that component is enabled or not. If the value is "false", **it overrides the component-specific values; all components are disabled**.
The default value is "true".

### package="com.Prasad.formdetails"

you should not use capital letters in package name . Use **package="com.prasad.formdetails"**

Comment: Thank you for that. 
But now another problem occurred. Can you check my database file. Don't know where things are going wrong. How to check it?

Comment: Dont know where the problem is. It is soembarrassing for me for not finding my own mistakes.. How to find them?

Comment: Yes. I just Debugged the code. Something is going wrong in DatabaseHandler.java file. Here is the link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277710/data-not-going-into-database-and-not-coming-from-database-in-android

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. You problem has been solved there.

Comment: no problem man. I always do silly mistakes. though it is not your duty to correct me, you are responding as soon as I asked. thanks for that. and sorry for late reply

Comment: @Krishna No problem . You will shine .

Comment: I think there is something waiting for your help. [please come here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881992/google-maps-v2-not-loading-error-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file/32882156#32882156)

Comment: @Krishna okay .Tell me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881992/google-maps-v2-not-loading-error-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file/32882156#32882156

Comment: @Krishna Glad to see that your problem solved .Move ahead once again

Comment: @Krishna Can i asking a question ? Where you from ? West bengal ,INDIA

Comment: No. Sorry for the late reply. I'm from hyderabad, Telengana, India. Where are you from? And sorry for that question. I thought you can answer that question. Thats why I disturbed you. But in the meanwhile that person answered it. Good to see my problem solved but still your time went in vain answering my question.

Comment: hello Amiya. How are you? I have doubt in networking and want to ask you. If you are willing to solve, can you help me?

Comment: Sorry for late reply .You can ask .have Facebook

Comment: @Krishna Check your FB .You can message me .I am in office

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's your `android:enabled="false"` in the application tag. Your package is disabled, hence your activity is disabled, too.