# Google Maps v2 not loading. Error android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line.. Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

This is my MainActivity. minimum sdk version is 11 in my app. I used the API key in the android manifest file. When I did some minor modifications, it is showing me blank white space instead of map.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}


}
```

This is my layout activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.prasad.maptrial.MainActivity"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.prasad.maptrial"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="(MY API KEY)" />   
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: use `SupportMapFragment` intead of `MapFragment`

Comment: At first use FragmentActivity instead of Activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mention this meta data tag

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

remove open gls tan andand let me know the result

Comment: same exception but now the line no. has changed to 7 instead of 6.

Comment: remove   android:name="com.prasad.maptrial.MainActivity" from layout

Comment: Worked for me. But what is the issue behind this. What is the matter with that meta-data. And also I included that line in layout file as that provided solution for some in stackoverflow who had the same problem

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_id))
            .getMap();
```

**From xml**

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/your_id"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Add your key here

```
 android:value="(MY API KEY)"
```

Comment: it will be better if you set `android:minSdkVersion="15"`

Comment: Thanks for spending some time here. My problem is solved. I marked it. Any ways I'll try your solution also. By the way, I used my key there. thought it would be a problem if I reveal it.