# getting Error inflating class fragment only in API 23

Tags: android-fragments, android-studio, google-play-services, google-maps-api-2

This has been the biggest headache for me. I've been following the tutorial at 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start?hl=en

but I always get a

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
```

ONLY on api 23. This is the most confusing part. Other APIs over 18 work fine.
I believe I've covered all the basic components,

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"

        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My google play version is up to date.(8487000)

I've tried placing the map fragment everywhere. Nothing seems to work.

activity_maps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/maps"
class ="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

MapsActivity:

```
package com.example.michael.myapplication;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity         implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881992/google-maps-v2-not-loading-error-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling on this:

Reinstall your emulator. Seriously. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing on emulator, try removing and creating AVD again. I was also facing that issue and that fixed for me.